# Prove that adding function symbols to a First Order Theory won't increase its deductive power.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, proof-theory

I'm trying to simplify some of my notes on FOL, and I came across a proposition that would greatly help me make much fewer messes.

Let $T$ be a theory in FOL, and suppose $T \vdash \exists_y p(x, y)$.

(If necessary, add also the constraint $T \vdash p(x,y) \wedge p(x, y') \rightarrow y = y'$)

Let $T'$ be the same theory, with a new function symbol $f$ added, with the axiom $p(x, f(x))$.

I wish to show that anything I can prove in $T'$ I can prove in $T$. That is, given a formula $\phi$ of $T$, if $T' \vdash \phi$ then $T \vdash \phi$.

I have managed to show an analogous proposition regarding the addition of propositional symbols, but the version of adding function symbols is proving more troublesome than I expected.

The book where I found this proposition (Schoenfield) uses some tools I'm trying to avoid unless I really have to use them, such as Prenex form and Herbrand's theorem. This seems like it should be doable in a more or less elementary way, but after butting my head against the wall for a few days I have come to math.stackexchange for help.

Comment: If you know the completeness theorem, you can give an easy semantic argument (by semantic, I mean: in terms of models). But if you want to use this proposition in a proof of the completeness theorem, then you need to use a proof-theoretic argument.

Comment: I do know the completeness theorem, but I would prefer a proof-theoretic, and hopefully constructive, approach.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Just to be sure, how would the semantic proof go? I'm thinking: Suppose $\phi$ provable in $T'$. Let $A$ be a model of $\phi$. Using the axiom of choice, find a function $f^A$ s.t. $p^A(x,f^A(x))$ for all $x$, so $A$ becomes a model of $T'$. Then $A\models \phi$. By Gödel completeness, $T\vdash \phi$. So it seems this only proves the theorem under the consistency of the meta-set-theory with choice.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro That's correct (though I think you meant to write "Let $A$ be a model of $T$"). Yes, it's a proof in a meta theory which is a set theory with choice (Aside: I don't agree with the phrase "proves the theorem under the consistency of the meta-theory". It's definitely a proof of the theorem! It's a totally separate question whether this is useful, based on whether the meta-theory is consistent or not). But the argument can be modified to avoid the use of choice, for a countable theory $T$ - recall that *the completeness theorem itself* requires some choice for general theories.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Here's a sketch: Suppose $T$ is countable. Let $A$ be a countable model of $T$. Since $A$ is countable, we may assume it has domain $\mathbb{N}$. Let $A'$ be $A$ expanded by the new function symbol $f$ as follows: For all $m\in \mathbb{N}$, $f^{A'}(m)$ is the least natural number $n$ such that $p(m,n)$. Then $A'\models T$, so $A'\models \phi$. But $\phi$ is a sentence in the language of $T$ (it doesn't mention $f$), so $A\models \phi$. Now we have shown that every countable model of $T$ satisfies $\phi$. It follows that $T\vdash \phi$. (continued in next comment)

Comment: Indeed, a variant of the completeness theorem, which is provable in ZF, says that if $T$ is a countable theory and every countable model of $T$ satisfies $\phi$, then $T \vdash \phi$. The point is that (1) we can assume the background language is countable, by ignoring any symbols that don't appear in $T$ and $\phi$, (2) it is possible to construct a completion of a theory in a countable language without using choice, (3) in the usual "Henkin constants" proof of the completeness theorem, we find that the model construction produces a countable model when the language is countable.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you very much for the details! I do agree the proof is indeed a proof... I should have phrased my concerns better. In any case, you dealt with them.